# Language and Currency

Tags: magento2.2.2

I want to display language and currency option in registration form so that when user login he get the home page in the language that he selected.
whether it is possible using admin?
Or I have to write code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to write custom module to create customer attribute where customer opt the language and can be redirected on that basis

Comment: Thank you but I need more coding info can you plz provide.